# Haskell: why is a multi-line let expression a syntax error?

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

Given the following,

```
module Foo where

main = do
  let foo = case 0 of
    0 -> 4
  return ()
```

GHC insists that I have a syntax error:

```
Make.hs:5:5: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
```

Why? I've used Haskell for a while, and it looks correct to me.

Comment: Have you checked the rules for indentation? It's clearly explained there

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Multiline expressions in do syntax must be indented beyond the variable name:

```
main = do
  let foo = case 0 of
       0 -> 4
  return ()
```

is ok but

```
main = do
  let foo = case 0 of
      0 -> 4
  return ()
```

is not.

Comment: To add, the reason is that `let` takes a block (like `do`) with multiple bindings—if you prefer a non-aligned style of indentation, you can break the line after `let` as you would with `do`.

Comment: This one constantly bites me. You'd expect indentation past the `let`, but it's actually indentation past the variable name. Putting the variable on its own line works, but looks fairly ugly.

Comment: This is really hard to see. The difference between the two examples is a space at the beginning of the '0 -> 4' line.